# How to sign in/out in Flask with AWS Cognito pool?

Tags: flask, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to sign in/out in my flask app with a user created on aws cognito, without success.

I first found about https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js which is mostly js. I'd prefer a (mostly) python solution, for maintainability reasons.

I tried using https://github.com/jetbridge/flask_cognito but don't understand how to actually integrate the initialization.

There are some questions related but old and mostly vague.

Comment: Did you find a way bro

Comment: wrote the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested in December 2020, I used [warrant](https://github.com/capless/warrant).

```
cognito_session = warrant.Cognito(
    username=email,
    user_pool_id=COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID,
    client_id=COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
    user_pool_region="us-east-1",
)
cognito_session.authenticate(password="password")
```

And then keep everything in a flask session. There are probably better alternatives. As of today (Oct 2021), there are probably better alternatives